# How do I make a fullscreen DIV where content is below?

Tags: html, responsive-design, fullscreen

I have been researching this and coming up empty-handed. I am even struggling how to search for this. I am looking to have a DIV element that is fullscreen & responsive. When they click the down arrow or scroll down, then the content appears. Can you help?

http://ivang-design.com/venus1/light/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you actually mean to create a "long scrolling page", then take a look at: [scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/)